# Trigger event when electron app switched to

Tags: html, electron

I have an electron app, and would like to fire off an event every time the app is in focus. For example, if I have my electron app and chrome open, and I switch to chrome, then back to electron, I want that event to fire. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the **focus** event for this.

In your BrowserWindow you have to:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow()
win.on('focus', () => {
   //do something
})
```

REF: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md